# Why do I get unstable measurements from a Fronius insolation sensor?

Tags: sensor, photodiode, light-sensor

I am using a Fronius insolation sensor to measure solar irradiation in a power facility. I keep track of the sensor's measurements through out the day and use them to display diagrams like this:

[image: correct irradiation diagram]

The problem with this specific sensor is that I get fluctuating values like this one in a clear sky:
[image: fluctuating irradiation diagram]

I need help to more specifically find out what is wrong with the sensor. If any more specific information is required I can provide it.

To exactly highlight the problem I should mention that a properly functioning insolation sensor is expected to provide a smooth curve of irradiation measurements from 7am to 5pm just like the first diagram. But the sensor used in the second diagram is providing irrelevant fluctuating values. I cannot quite understand why, because I'm not an expert in electronics and I have already tried calibrating the sensor.

I need help to understand what could possibly cause problems like this for an insolation sensor? Is the sensor malfunctioning or could it be cause of my wrong calibration or improper installation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bad power supply or long signal lines? Not enough details about the setup. Cover it up or take it indoors and shine a bright light at it and see if you still get noise.